# How to dynamically change the value of a variable

Tags: php, dynamic

I have a dropdown menu with a list of clients,and through that dropdown administrator can choose the client that he wants to log in with.

Example: Dropdown has Client 1,client 2 etc.,Administrator is logged in with his Admin account,he chooses Client 1,and after that he's logged as Client 1,not as Admin.
To validate that I store the data in the $_SESSION variable,to see how is someone logged in as.

The thing I don't know how to do is how can i change the value of `$_SESSION['something']` variable without refreshing the page every time Admin chooses some other client.Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is a pre-processor (the script runs before the page is loaded) I don't think you would be able to achieve this without using a different programming language.